# msgraph: how to create a batch request for subscriptions using GraphServiceClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a batch request that will create multiple graph notification subscriptions in a single request.

I've been reading this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp

**Problem**

I'm getting the following error message but I don't know how to address it:

```
(local variable) Task<Subscription> userRequest
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.Graph.Subscription>' to 'Microsoft.Graph.BatchRequestStep'
```

**Code**

```
        var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GenerateGraphAuthToken(this.amParms);

        foreach (string userId in this.UserstoSubscribe)
        {
                var subscription = new Subscription
                    {
                        ChangeType = "updated",
                        NotificationUrl= notificationURL,
                        Resource = $"users/{userId}/drive/root",
                        ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(subscriptionDate),
                        ClientState = "secretClientValue",
                        LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
                    };
                    var userRequest =  graphClient.Subscriptions
                        .Request()
                        .AddAsync(subscription);
                    var userRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(userRequest);
        }
       var returnedResponse = await graphClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);
```

Any tips would be appreciated.  Sorry.  I'm just new to .NET and to MS Graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddBatchRequestStep` method expects as a parameter either `BatchRequestStep` or `IBaseRequest` or `HttpRequestMessage`.
In your case you have a `POST` request, so you must get the `HttpRequestMessage` and convert to a `POST`.

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    ChangeType = "updated",
    NotificationUrl= notificationURL,
    Resource = $"users/{userId}/drive/root",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(subscriptionDate),
    ClientState = "secretClientValue",
    LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
};
// create a json content from the subscription
var jsonSubscription = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(subscription);

// create a HttpRequestMessage, specify the method and add the json content
var userRequest = graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
userRequest.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
userRequest.Content = jsonSubscription;

// add userRequest to a batch request content
var userRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(userRequest);
```

Comment: what's "client" in this context?  Sorry.  I'm super green.  Ah maybe graphClient

Comment: @dot yes, it's graphClient. Edited my answer.